# Pass Data to Step Function From HTTP API Gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, aws-step-functions

I have a Step Function integration with one of my routes in API Gateway. My API is an HTTP API. It has the following settings:

[image: StepFunctions]

This is successfully invoking my StepFunction but I am unable to access any of my body parameters. This route is being invoked from a front-end form which submits data. I would like to use this data for further processing in my step functions.

When I see my step function execution, the input is just {}, is there something I need to change?

Comment: Passing in data from API gateway to step functions has a much smaller data load than the AWS Lambda invocation. I opted to reduce my load and instead of invoking my step function from API gateway, I passed data to my Lambda function and used my lambda function to invoke my step function.

Answer (score 1):

In the advanced settings set a value for "Input - optional" of "$request.body"

Answer (score 0):

You can pass multiple values as inputs by enclosing the variables in brackets. For example, ${request.path.name} ${request.path.id}.

You can even put the following values in the input field `{"name": "${request.path.name}", "id": "${request.path.id}" }` and it will work.

You can read more about this in the [AWS API Gateway docs, Transforming API requests and responses](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/http-api-parameter-mapping.html) section.